# DELL R720 Server's esxi6.7 is not pinging after installing the ubuntu server on separate HDD point to same NIC1 in Home Lab

Tags: ubuntu, esxi, dell

Dell R720 server has hypervisor ESXi 6.7 running eve_ng Lab for networking Lab. Recently I installed an Ubuntu server on a separate HDD pointing same NIC1 in DHCP mode, Now **Idrac 7 does not show the ESXi in the virtual console nor can ping within the network**. Although I have moved the Ubuntu server to the NIC-2 and kept it on DHCP mode, no log shows any errors in Idrac.

**is my ESXi crashed, do I need to rebuild the whole Lab all over again?**

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.